# scikit-learn SelectPercentile TFIDF data feature reduction

Tags: python, text, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using the various mechanisms in scikit-learn to create a tf-idf representation of a training data set and a test set  consisting of text features. Both data sets are preprocessed to use the same vocabulary so the features and the number of features are the same. I can create a model on the training data and assess its performance on the test data. I am wondering if I use SelectPercentile to reduce the number of features in the training set after transformation, how can identify the same features in the test set to utilise in prediction?

```
trainDenseData = trainTransformedData.toarray()
testDenseData = testTransformedData.toarray()

if ( useFeatureReduction== True):
    reducedTrainData = SelectPercentile(f_regression,percentile=10).fit_transform(trainDenseData,trainYarray)

clf.fit(reducedTrainData, trainYarray)


# apply feature reduction to the test data
```

Answer (score 1):

See code and comments below.

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn import feature_selection

# Build a classification task using 3 informative features
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                           n_features=10,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_redundant=0,
                           n_repeated=0,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           shuffle=False)

sp = feature_selection.SelectPercentile(feature_selection.f_regression, percentile=30)
sp.fit_transform(X[:-1], y[:-1])  #here, training are the first 9 data vectors, and the last one is the test set
idx = np.arange(0, X.shape[1])  #create an index array
features_to_keep = idx[sp.get_support() == True]  #get index positions of kept features

x_fs = X[:,features_to_keep] #prune X data vectors
x_test_fs = x_fs[-1] #take your last data vector (the test set) pruned values
print x_test_fs #these are your pruned test set values
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store the `SelectPercentile` object, and use it to `transform` the test data:

```
select = SelectPercentile(f_regression,percentile=10)
reducedTrainData = select.fit_transform(trainDenseData,trainYarray)
reducedTestData = select.transform(testDenseData)
```